# How to make an exotic font the default through the whole document

Tags: fonts

How can I use a font that needs explicit calling, like [Auriocus Kalligraphicus](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/aurical/), as the default font through the whole document?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could redefine `\familydefault`, `\rmdefault`, `\sfdefault` and more.

Regarding Auriocus Kalligraphicus, for example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{aurical}
\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{AuriocusKalligraphicus}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Text}
This is an example.
\end{document}
```

As you can see, roman text in various sizes has the desired font:

[image]