# How to use  \sffamily for the whole document

Tags: fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simplest way to typeset entire document in sans serif (Helvetica)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2095/simplest-way-to-typeset-entire-document-in-sans-serif-helvetica)

How to use `\sffamily` for the whole document?

Comment: Related questions: ["How to make an exotic font the default through the whole document"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12586/2975), ["How to use different font for full document in LaTeX"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12826/2975).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
```

See [`fntguide`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/fntguide.pdf) for more information.