# How to set a default font to a page in latex?

Tags: fontsize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to specify font size less than 10pt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5339/how-to-specify-font-size-less-than-10pt)

How to set those fonts to my page in latex: font is Computer Modern sans serif with normal size 8 pt?

Comment: Do you mean `\sffamily`?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Yes but how to set this to the whole document as default?

Comment: @IonMorozan: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13265/how-to-use-sffamily-for-the-whole-document