# Create font package to use custom vectorial symbols via FontForge

Tags: symbols, python, matplotlib, fontforge

This question builds upon [my attempt to include custom, vectorial, LaTeX symbols inside Python plots via `tikz`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/610992/creating-new-symbols-with-full-font-metrics-and-vector-quality), which (so far) is [failing due to the impossibility (my inability ?) to attach proper font metric elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68769147/tikzpicture-cropped-from-dvi-when-used-in-matplotlib-plt-text/68812674#68812674) to the symbols.

Hence, I am now attempting to use FontForge to create an actual font for my custom symbols, which I then want/need to properly package in the hope to facilitate their installation via CTAN.

But I cannot seem to properly "bundle" the FontForge products into a LaTeX package. I have tried to follow [the FontForge documentation](https://fontforge.org/docs/techref/PfaEdit-TeX.html), as well as [these step-by-step explanations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14951/using-a-local-font-for-a-few-maths-symbols). There are many other FontForge-LateX related posts and questions out there, but I could find none clarifying a full (and clean) procedure to go from font creation to a fully-fledged package assembly.

**What I have done so far:**

1. Creation of `.pfb`, `.asm`, `.otf`, `.enc`, and `.tfm` files from FontForge, with encoding set to TeX, and one test symbol (a simple circle) as the `0` glyph.
2. Compiling the following test document, which **does** display my symbol just fine:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}

   \pdfmapline{=mysymb mysymb <mysymb.pfb}

   \begin{document}
   \font\test=mysymb \test 0
   \end{document}
   ```
3. Creation of `umysymb.fd` with the following content:

   ```
   \ProvidesFile{umysymb.fd}
   \DeclareFontFamily{U}{mysymb}{}
   \DeclareFontShape{U}{mysymb}{m}{n}{<-> mysymb}{}
   ```

   **Edit 24.08.2021:** mind the `u` at the start of the `.fd` file name! See @Marcel Krüger's comment. This solves the following error message (otherwise issued when compiling the test document below):

   ```
   LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/mysymb/m/n' undefined
   ```
4. Creation of `mysymb.sty` with the following content:

   ```
   \newcommand{\mysymbol}{{\usefont{U}{mysymb}{m}{n} 0}}
   ```
5. Creation of `mysymb.map` with the following content:

   ```
   mysymb mysymb <mysymb.pfb
   ```
6. Update of the *system map info* via the command:

   ```
   sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=mysymb.map
   ```

   This solves the following error message (otherwise issued when trying to compile the test document shown at the next point):

   ```
   kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 mysymb
   mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for mysymb.
   mktexpk: perhaps mysymb is missing from the map file.
   ```
7. At this point, the following test document compiles without issue, and **does** display my symbol:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{mysymb}

   \begin{document}
   Hello World. Here's a new symbol: \mysymbol
   \end{document}
   ```
8. Placement of the following files with my TeX-tree in the appropriate location. In my case, my `tex_loc` is `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/`, but this is clearly user/OS dependent:

   ```
   cp metsymb.tfm tex_loc/fonts/tfm/public/metsymb/
   cp metsymb.afm tex_loc/fonts/afm/public/metsymb/
   cp metsymb.pfb tex_loc/fonts/type1/public/metsymb/
   cp metsymb.otf tex_loc/fonts/opentype/public/metsymb/
   cp umetsymb.fd tex_loc/tex/latex/metsymb/
   cp metsymb.sty tex_loc/tex/latex/metsymb/
   cp metsymb.map tex_loc/fonts/map/dvips/metsymb/
   cp metsymb.enc tex_loc/fonts/enc/dvips/metsymb/
   ```
9. At this point, the package and associated test symbol can be seen by my Python scripts.

**Open question:**
How do I then properly package all of these files to allow for a solid CTAN install ?

As of 24.08.2021, I have created the necessary `.ins`, `.dtx` and can successfully generate the `.sty` file from these.

The last remaining step is to figure out whether all of it can be placed as-is (or not) on CTAN, to be handled automatically by package managers.

Comment: `mysymb.fd` should be called `umysymb.fd`.

Comment: Thank you for this ! With that change, I hit the same "don't know how to create bitmap font" error, which I could fix using `sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=mysymb.map` following [this hint](https://de.comp.text.tex.narkive.com/WNUWAlho/minionpro-don-t-know-how-to-create-bitmap-font). I'm now moving on to the proper packaging of all these elements ...

Answer (score 2):

The package was recently uploaded to [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/metsymb) from its [Github repository](https://github.com/MeteoSwiss/metsymb), where a dedicated [Github Action](https://github.com/MeteoSwiss/metsymb/blob/develop/.github/workflows/CI_assemble-ctan-zip.yml) was assembled to automatically create a CTAN-compatible ZIP file when a new release is being issued.